# List comprehensions with nested lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Would like to ask question related to nested lists in Python.

I have a nested list

```
list_1 = [[1,3,0,1], [1,1,0,2,3,0,4,], [2,1,2,2,3,4]]
```

I want to perform rounding and dision operation on nested list but keep it grouped as it is now (to make it more clear I need to flatten list perform operations and that unflatten it again in same groups).

For example the result for list 'list_1' after division by 2 shoud be

```
list_2 = [[0.5,1.5,0,0.5],[0.5,0.5,0,1,1.5,0,2],[1,0.5,1,1,1.5,2]]
```

The code I use to perform this for signle list is below:

```
list_2 = [round(b,2) for b in [a / 2 for a in list_1]]
```

Could you please suggest way to solve this issue. Currently I am getting error

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using `NumPy`? Alternatively (especially if your lists are not rectangular), use nested list comprehension. Python itself does not allow to broadcast arithmetic operations.

Comment: Your `list_2` output seems to be missing an element in the first sublist?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Could you please suggest a link, where I can see sample of using NumPy for this type of operations? I couldn't find similar case myself.

Comment: This is a foundational operation in NumPy. Read any good numpy tutorial.

Comment: Delirious Lettuce, good catch. Corrected.

Comment: @GAG How does `round(1 / 2, 2) == 1.5` in the first element of the second sublist?

Comment: @Delirious Lettuce  - should be 0.5. Corrected. list_2 results I wrtoe by hand, just to make what I want to get more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixing your code -

```
[[j / 2. for j in i] for i in list_1]
```

If you're worried about performance, you could multiply by .5 instead of dividing by 2 (you may not see *significant* differences considering this is a quadratic solution, but it should count for *something*).

```
[[j * .5 for j in i] for i in list_1]
```

The docs have a section just for [Nested List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions), please consider having a read through.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ community wiki: classy. BTW if OP is using python 2 the result will be incorrect.

Comment: multiplication is faster than division: `j * 0.5` is probably slightly faster :)